# psql major version 13, server major version 14

Tags: postgresql, psql

In Windows Powershell,  `psql  --version`  return: `psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2`
After I logged in one database, `SELECT version();`  returns

```
 PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I already installed PostgreSQL 14 and PostgreSQL 13.
Now What should I do to make psql version to be 14.
`psql.exe` appears on `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin`, also on `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin`
I already set `postgresql` environment variable to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin`

[image: issue]

[image: psql --version]

Comment: Can you share the command output of `where psql`

Comment: @SahapAsci I attached the psql picture.

Comment: well, you haven't provided the output of the command `where psql`

Comment: @SahapAsci, it on C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin, also on C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin.

Comment: Try: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\psql.exe -U postgres`, if this helps you might need to remove postgres 13 from your PATH environment variable (or completely remove it)